# sqlite3 Interface error on inserting data to database

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

i am using sqlite3 to store data to database. I have created lineedits through which i extract the data and insert it to database. But now the problem is when i run the program,once i click on add data button the above error shown. Please help me where am i going wrong.....Another thing is that if i run the same code in windows platform its runs without any problem, but if in ubuntu 13.4 it is not working..........here is the code:

```
  queryCurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PATIENT
    (NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,AGE INTEGER NOT NULL,GENDER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,EYE_TYPE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)''')

   self.pName = self.patientEdit.text()
   self.pAge = self.ageEdit.text()
   self.pGender = self.patientgend.text()
   self.pEye_type = self.eyeTypeEdit.text()

   queryCurs.execute('''INSERT INTO PATIENT(NAME,AGE,GENDER,EYE_TYPE) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)''',(self.pName,self.pAge,self.pGender,self.pEye_type))
    print ('Inserted row')
    createDb.commit()
```

this what i have tried in my code...i get error as
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)''',(self.pName,self.pAge,self.pGender,self.pEye_type))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: And what is the type of `pName`?

Comment: `pName` is a Python variable.